# FYI: In Phonegap APP for Windows Phone Console.log in change object type into String

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone

FYI

Phonegap build for Windows Phone

I found that if we console any object it change object data type into string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way which I used, create your own logger and before logging create a clone of object so your object will be save.

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

function MyLogger(realMsg) {
        var msg = clone(realMsg);
        console.log(msg);
}
```